# What is the name for tag questions in Spanish?

Tags: gramática, preguntas

Does the [tag question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_question) kind in Spanish have any particular name?
I can't find anything similar in [RAE website](http://www.rae.es).

Tag questions would be something like:

> He read this book, **didn't he?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In English, *tag questions* have a specific name because of their particular construction, that you must learn (including some particular cases, such as "I am..., aren't I?"). In Spanish you don't need to learn any specific construction, as tag questions are simply like this:

> Él se ha leído este libro, ¿verdad?
>   Él se ha leído este libro, ¿no?
>   Él se ha leído este libro, ¿cierto?

Being the first option the most common one, at least in Spain. If you want, you can say that they are *preguntas de confirmación*. In the *Nueva gramática española* you can find these constructions as ***apéndices confirmativos***, ***apéndices interrogativos*** or ***muletillas interrogativas*** among other names, as written [in paragraph 42.8a](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=bGzFqFAAgdgAgNkU).

Comment: Very good research! (edited)

Comment: @fedorqui Turns out that the NGE has indeed a name for these questions...

Answer (score 2):

I've always used a question tag by just saying: *¿o no?*

What's easier in Spanish language is that you don't need to refer to the grammar structure when it comes to using a tag.

1. El lee el libro, ¿o no?
2. El leyó el libro, ¿o no?
3. El leería el libro, ¿o no?

Unlike English, you need to say *Doesn't he? Didn't he? Wouldn't he?*